# projected are of a sphere

Tags: geometry

I am trying to find the projected area of a sphere. I know that I should get that the projected area is a fourth of the surface area, but I do not understand the process of getting there. If I could get a step by step in math on how to get the answer that would be great. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Prove that the surface area of a unit sphere is $4\pi$, check that the area enclosed by an equator is $\pi$ and notice that $\frac{\pi}{4\pi}=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: The projection is perpendicular to the plane and it is really the disk created by the tangent rays , the disk created by the intersection of the sphere with a plane through it's center.